# Can ONE site with Shopware 6 handle multiple products in multiple currencies and languages?

Tags: shopware6

We are on Woocommerce (WC) and thinking of migrating to Shopware 6.

He have multiple WC servers one for each sub domain, currently on 6 and will end of each be on 10 servers...

https://fr.theuntamed.com - French with EUR
https://es.theuntamed.com - Spanish with EUR
https://pl.theuntamed.com - Polish with PLN

etc...

It's very time consuming to maintain code on all WC servers.

Can this be done in Shopware 6 much easier?

What we looking for is to show unique product portfolio for each market (each sub domain) with their local currency and language. Of course this would be the same case for all content that also need to be in local language.

**We don't use any language or currency plugins in WC and would not like to use it in Shopware 6.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Shopware 6 there are translations as well as storefronts.

For each market you would create a storefront and you can activate / deactivate products based on each storefront.

For each translation, you can add the different languages withing a storefront. So for example you can also manage German and French in a swiss storefront.

The subdomains can be configured in the storefront settings under "domains".

You do not need different servers for this, it can be all managed under one Shopware 6 installation.